# How to keep an outer class while obfuscating the inner classes

Tags: proguard

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {
  private class MyInnerClass {
    public void someFunc() { }
  }

  public void usefulMethod() {
    ... some stuff...
    nativeUsefulMethod();
  }

  private native void nativeUsefulMethod();
}
```

I need to keep the method names of all native functions, as well as the classes containing them, in order for the native code to work properly. Seems like no problem:

```
-keepnames class * {
  native <methods>;
}
```

When I look at the resulting jar, I see that MyClass and nativeUsefulMethod() remain, while usefulMethod() has been obfuscated. Good. However, the inner class is still named "MyClass$MyInnerClass". It contains no native methods, so I would expect it to be called "MyClass$a" or just "a".

I tested changing "-keepnames" to "-keepclassmembernames", and the class names of both get obfuscated. It's definitely this directive that's keeping the inner class name. Is there a way to obfuscate the outer, but not the inner class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper configuration for native methods is:

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

See the ProGuard manual > Examples > [Processing native methods](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native)

Comment: Indeed, I discovered that independently but didn't go back and check the result. -keepnames class * { ... } causes *all* class names to be kept, and I only noticed it on the inner class. When using the proper directive, the inner classes are properly obfuscated.